# passing parameter via url in Laravel4 is not working

Tags: php, laravel-4

It is possible to pass parameter to the page using controller via `->with()` for example

```
public function two(){

 return View::make('page2')->with('id', 2);

}
```

and now `$id` can be accessible in `page2.blade.php`

But i want to pass parameters via url with array like the way below

routes.php

```
<?php
Route::get('page1', 
array(
'uses' => 'pagecontroller@page1'

));

Route::get('page2/{$id}',
 array(
 'uses'=>'pagecontroller@page2'
 ));
```

pagecontroller.php

```
<?php

class pagecontroller extends BaseController{


  public function page1(){

   return View::make('page1');

  }

  public function page2($id){

    return "ID : $id";

  }
```

page1.blade.php

```
<p>This Is Page1</p>

<a href="{{action('pagecontroller@page2', array('id'=>1)  )}}">Page2</a>
```

And it is showing the error : `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`

Where is it going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little typo in your routes. The parameter is defined without the "$" prefix.

`Route::get('page2/{$id}',`

should be

`Route::get('page2/{id}',`

Remember to do `composer dump-autoload` after you change your routes.php file.

You might want to take a moment and check out the docs on routing params 
http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters